# Yii2 Progress Bar in a GridView

Tags: gridview, yii2

I have an scale value between 0-100 in model. When I display list of models in the GridView, I would like to display a line chart or progress bar instead of numerical value. Is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

To me this works properly

```
    <?=
GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => [
        [
            'content' => function($model) {
                return ProgressBar::widget([
                    'clientOptions' => [
                        'value' => $model->getDownloadingStatus(),
                    ],
                ]);
            },
        ],
    ],
]);
?>
```

In model the getDownloadingStatus() functions return values between 0 and 100. Of course you could use static value 'value' => 50, or sth similar

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap 3 can use its progress bar.It is used as a normal class. Then you can assign it to the options field that interests you, or do `echo`  the html needed. The following are the html. for more detail you can see [getbootstrap progress](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress)

```
<div class="progress">
  <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="60" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 60%;">
60%
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it too late to respond on a old question. But hope my answer may help someone someday.

```
    [
      'attribute' => 'job_comp',
      'format' => 'html',
      'filter' => false,
      'value' => function ($data) {
      $status = $data->job_comp; // Assigning to a variable for if condition for dynamic classes.
      if ($status <= '25') {
      $class = 'bg-danger';
      } else if ($status > '25' && $status <= '50') {
      $class = 'bg-secondary';
      } else if ($status > '50' && $status <= '75') {
      $class = 'bg-info';
      } else if ($status > '75') {
      $class = 'bg-success';
      }
      return  '<div class="progress-showcase">  <div class="progress" style="height: 8px;"> <div class="progress-bar ' . $class . '" title="' . $data->job_comp . '%" role="progressbar" style="width:' . $data->job_comp . '%" aria-valuenow="50" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100"></div></div></div>';
      },
],
```

You can use this method if you are using **Bootstrap** style sheets.